# Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'UInt8'

Tags: swift, binary, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

I wish to perform simple `or` logic on 2 bit maps, yet Swift thinks this is wrong:

```
let u: UInt8 = 0b1
let i: Int = 0b10
i | u // Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'UInit8'
```

Any way to conform to type inference and still have this working?

I could always do `i | Int(u) // 3` but this, I think, is not optimal.

Comment: Swift does not implicitly convert between types, that is one of its fundamental principles. `i | Int(u)` is the correct solution here (in my opinion) because it forces you to think about what the result type should be. – Think about `Int(2) | UInt(3)`, should that evaluate to an `Int` or `UInt` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the fundamental principles of Swift is that is does not implicitly
convert between types.

```
let u: UInt8 = 0b1
let i: Int = 0b10
i | Int(u)
```

forces you to think about the necessary conversions and what type the result should have,
so that *is* the correct solution (in my opinion).

Let's consider another example:

```
let u: UInt8 = 128
let i: Int8 = -128
```

What should `u|i` be? Both

```
u | UInt8(i)
Int8(u) | i
```

crash at runtime because `u` is not in the range of an `Int8`, and `i` is not 
in the range of an `UInt8`. Both

```
u | UInt8(bitPattern: i)   // result is `UInt8`
Int8(bitPattern: u) | i    // result is `Int8`
```

would work, but how should the compiler choose between both?
 One could convert both to some larger type, for example

```
Int(u) | Int(i)
```

but that type is somewhat arbitrary, how could it automatically be inferred from the compiler? And what is the "larger type"
for `Int64` + `UInt64` arguments?

That's why I think that an explicit conversion is the right solution.